# Multi vendor marketplace script/framework/saas to fit my need

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart

A search for 'multi vendor marketplace' yields a ton of results but it's hard to evaluate to land on the best one for my needs.
We are a Southern African ecommerce company looking to open a 'Etsy' type marketplace for local vendors to sell physical goods. My primary track is to purchase a framework of this type, put it on our server and have our in-house development team modify and customize it to our specs, some of which are:

- Currency must be our local curreny
- we must be able to integrate with the payment gateway of our choice
- We must be able to modify the check out process to be able to take cash in exhange for handing over the physical item at our cash-points.

We are looking at Yo!Kart but the fact that they don't have an official API was a red flag, and they seem eager to 'help' customize it for a fee. I would prefer something that we buy, get full access to modify, take ownership of, and that has a good solid API already. Then if that is not enough, THEN we can start modifying the source code.
Functionality wise I like Etsy's model were store owners can brand their own stores and it's quite easy to reach individual stores but you can shop simultaniously from different stores. You can also contact each store easily.

I hope somebody can give some good recommendations that fit these criteria. I was unsure if I should post this in 'Web Applications' or here, sorry if it's the wrong place.

Comment: Hi. Please confirm which solution you went with in the end. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using a multivendor plug-in for the Woocommerce plugin for Wordpress to create a proof-of concept site that could be used as a first step. It never got further than that.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know if a particular solution fits those needs, without actually setting it up to test.  However here is a link where someone had a similar question, and they found a solution to setting up their own etsy-like hosting service using WordPress and the plugin MarketPress.  Read the first response which includes links to tutorial videos.

[wpmudev.org](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/hosting-my-own-network-of-stores-like-etsy-or-ebay)

Given the open source nature and global influence of WP, it seems like a good possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which I also use myself for an installation, is to use [commerce marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/maciej.zgadzaj/1950386) which is a drupal module (open source framework/content management). To quote:

> Module package providing overrides for default Drupal Commerce
>   behaviors allowing to use DC-based stores to create multiple-merchant
>   marketplace (like Etsy, Amazon, etc).

Of course, it means you need to learn how to use drupal if you do not already do so. But it offers flexibility to add more functionality, tweak to suit your requirements, or write own custom modules. It is not an "out-of-the-box" solution as you need to install/configure modules to suit your use case.

1. You can have own local currency.
2. You can integrate with payment gateways. If a module does not already exist for your specific payment provider, you can write custom module for this.
3. Cash checkout module also exists.