# Open source software for second hand items marketplace

Tags: open-source

Do you know any open source software (for either website or app) for selling used items? I mean a marketplace for second hand items just like [www.carousell.sg](https://www.carousell.sg).

- No payment in app
- No sipping in app

Carousell is for both website and app. And you can rate the seller and read reviews.

Comment: How do you plan to handle payments? Obviously, in some way, a third party payment-processor must be involved but which one?

Comment: Just curious, what is "sipping "?

Answer (score 1):

Opensource content management systems like drupal, wordpress, etc. have modules for ecommerce which can probably be used for your purposes.

Please see a previous answer I posted here using [drupal commerce](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/multi-vendor-marketplace-script-framework-saas-to-fit-my-need/31254#31254), even though a bit old now.

Also, another system to check out is [Opencart](https://www.opencart.com)

I suggest you clarify the specific functionality you are looking for e.g.

- is it one vendor or multiple vendors?
- what payment methods will be made available? For instance, if multiple vendors, site may need to take commission out of payments...
- potential number of products/transactions per day
- hosted or self-hosted?
- how to handle shipping, freight, postage charges?
- and so on...

This will help narrow down which system to use.